Is there any way to add custom pages to Clerk <UserProfile /> component in Next js App Router
I've been trying to add custom page to user profile, but it doesn't seem to work.
I have firgured out how to achive that with the  but not with any other component. Any help would be much appreciated!
<UserButton>
                            <UserButton.UserProfilePage label="Public Profile" url="profile" labelIcon={<BiSolidUserDetail
                            className={'text-base'}/>}>
                                <SettingsPage />
                            </UserButton.UserProfilePage>
                            <UserButton.MenuItems>
                                <UserButton.Link
                                    label="View profile"
                                    labelIcon={<HiUser />}
                                    href="/my-profile"
                                />
                            </UserButton.MenuItems>
                        </UserButton>

I tried having  component in app/user-profile/[[...user-profile]]/page.js and then adding custom page. It didn't work either.
